# Form validator framework which is works with PHP 5.2?

Tags: php, validation

can anyone recommend a php form validator framework which is works with PHP 5.2.17?

Already tried:

- https://github.com/Respect/Validation - looks good but does not support the 5.2 version.
- Kohana validator - looks like it can work with 5.2 but i do not know where can i download only the validation related code, and seems like it is deeply integrated into the framework.

Comment: [Symfony 1.4 Validator](http://symfony.com/legacy/doc/forms/1_4/en/02-Form-Validation) works with 5.2.14?

Answer (score 0):

PHP has some decent built-in validators, including e-mail address validation.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php

Comment: You realize this isn't answering the question, right?

Comment: Thanks for your response, I changed the question to make it clearer.

Comment: What do you mean? If PHP can do something natively, why not use that? OP, are you using a Symfony already for your project? There is a difference between a framework and a library.

Comment: @LeeSalminen - Use `@` and the username to notify someone (one per comment) that you are talking to them. Like at the beginning of this comment.